# Let's shut down the [airport]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

About half of the questions under the [airport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/airport) tag are asking questions about [Apple's wireless products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPort), such as their line of AirPort wireless routers. These routers do not have any documented or reverse-engineered programming interface, so it's essentially impossible to ask any programming questions about them. (With the exception of "is there an API", to which the answer is "no".) Most of the questions under this tag are questions about configuring or using these routers, which is off-topic for Stack Overflow — please help me close these questions.

The remainder of the questions under this tag are misusing it (according to the tag wiki) for questions referring to actual airports, typically requesting data sources for information about airports. Most of these are also off-topic as recommendation questions; please help me close them as well.

Comment: I remove the tag from three of them ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109810/is-there-an-api-for-realtime-airport-information), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176619/web-service-for-searching-airports-in-us), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550401/worldwide-airport-listing)), but I'm wondering if actually we shouldn't since then they get orphaned from cleanup. Hmm...

Comment: 80% of what I'm looking at needs to be closed, so I wouldn't remove the tag. Ping me once it's cleaned up, and I'll bulk remove it.

Comment: Very strange logic.  The vast majority of my answers are about undocumented stuff.  Programmers ask questions *because* it is undocumented.  If it is documented then an RTFM link in a comment is all it takes.

Comment: @HansPassant "These routers do not have any documented **or reverse-engineered** programming interface, so _it's essentially impossible to ask any programming questions about them_." Take a look at the questions, it's mostly new users asking how to configure a certain feature of their device - which may be on topic for SuperUser but is definitely out of scope for SO. If you disagree that the tag needs to be cleaned up, please give specific arguments how it is valid for programming questions.

Comment: It's fine to ask questions about stuff you find while just poking the devices. While formats and such might not be documented, folks _can_ figure it out and share it. What I'm talking about are the number of "how do I plug this thing in?" kinds of questions which (unfortunately) the tag seems to be attracting.

Comment: If there are legit questions, the tag can stay - we can provide some just-in-time help letting folks using it know that the question has to be about _programming_ and see how that goes. Let's see what's left post-cleanup.

Comment: @TimPost I'm struggling to think of actual programming-related questions one could possibly ask with the tag. It's not like anybody who buys an apple router will attempt installing dd-wrt on it or otherwise hack the firmware. Maybe for security research, but even then reprogramming the device seems rather outlandish...

Comment: [Airport](https://github.com/okcoker/jquery-airport) is apparently also a JQuery plugin. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343941/jquery-airport-plugin-does-not-show-non-english-characters (Who knew that even airports needed JQuery?)

Comment: I spent some time going through all the questions in the airport tag, closed the off topic posts and deleted the unsalvagable ones. There are 10 questions remaining in this tag, which looks on-topic to me. Can you do a scan through all these 10 posts and then poke @TimPost to remove the tag?

Comment: I've whittled this down to 4, with 3 of them closed or with active CVs to close them as Gen Computing. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33223457/mac-osx-el-capitan-airport-sym-link-not-permitted) also appears to be Gen Computing but it's popular. Maybe remove the tag and historical lock? Once that's done, tag is burninated

Comment: @Machavity, removed the tag from that, there was no need for a historical lock.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The final flight has departed. This tag has been removed.

Comment: Only took two years?